# Redirect back to application and display custom error page when user fails to sign in to Okta

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth, okta, okta-api

I am using Okta for authentication within an Angular app. When the user visits the application they are taking to the https://dev-111111.oktapreview.com/login/login.htm login form. If the user signs in successfully they are taken back to the application which is perfect. However, if the user fails to login the Okta login form says Sign in failed!.

I prefer that instead of the form saying this, that the user is taken back to the application so I can display a custom error page.

Is this possible?

Comment: You really need to add in relevant code, or there's no chance to help you

Comment: What code could I possibly add? I am telling you everything is working fine. I get to the Okta login form, if a user fails to login, I prefer redirecting back to the Angular app rather than staying on the Okta login form page. I am asking if this is possible or not.

Comment: The login form. Authentication services. How the redirect route works. Etc. Okta is just a wrapper. You are in control of all of the front end code that you're talking about, and that code exists somewhere so show it